# String Replace first line and last line

Tags: javascript, regex, xml, collections

I have the following string returned by my system as xml

```
<select>
<unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="1639" recipientId="76391"/>
<unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="49308" recipientId="76391"/>
<unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="2447" recipientId="76391"/>
<unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="9225" recipientId="76391"/>
<unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="24527" recipientId="76391"/>
</select>
```

I need the parent `select` element to match the following.

```
<unsubscriptionLink-collection xtkschema="nms:unsubscriptionLink">
    <unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="4151" recipientId="1000" url="http://www.google.com"/>
    <unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="4151" recipientId="1030" url="http://www.google.com"/>
    <unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="4151" recipientId="1031" url="http://www.google.com"/>
    <unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="4151" recipientId="1060" url="http://www.google.com"/>
    <unsubscriptionLink deliveryId="4151" recipientId="1090" url="http://www.google.com"/>
</unsubscriptionLink-collection>
```

Is there a way to replace the first ocurrence of `select` to match `<unsubscriptionLink-collection xtkschema="nms:unsubscriptionLink">`

And also the last line `</select>` to `</unsubscriptionLink-collection>` I can only use javascript.also, the complete number of items will be 10k rows, so rather than scanning the whole payload, Is better to focus on finding the first line select and the last line select. (does javascript allow to scan from back to front and front to back using regex?)

[image: response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow `x` to be your string content:

```
const innerStart = x.indexOf(">") + 1;
const innerEnd = x.lastIndexOf("<");

const inner = x.slice(innerStart, innerEnd);
```

You can then wrap the `inner` xml with your new tag.  I would not use a regex until you have to.

Comment: Like the following? https://jsfiddle.net/b1eph9y4/1/

Comment: Yes!  Does that work for what you need?  I was assuming you already have the content in memory like that.

Comment: yeah seems like it does the job, is there any concern on performance, does indexOf scans the whole string?

Comment: It will return once it finds a match, only scanning as far as it needs.  There does seem to be an argument that a simple for loop is faster, but the performance reports seem dubious.

Comment: Razu, how do I configure it to remove top 2 and bottom 2?

Comment: indexOf can take a second argument indicating a starting index of the search. So you could call index of once, then use that to call it a second time. Although you may just want a loop at this point.